# masm как сделать массив с изменяемой длиной

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, arraylist, masm32

Возможно ли изменить длинну массива (dd) и затем записать её в eax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И нет, и да. Дело в том, что результат декларации dd - просто последовательность байт в бинарнике, которая статически грузится в память.

Так что менять размер тут просто нечему. dd не является командой динамического выделения памяти - она просто статически помещает в бинарник нужную последовательность байт.

Хотите выделить память - обратитесь к операционной системе и попросите. Через системный вызов.

Comment: а как вот правильно обратиться к операционной системе, чтоб она выделила память?

Comment: Это мне подойдёт? если да, то как мне это можно было бы переделать под masm32 (windows10)?
http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?120